# WinHugs - how to declare a variable and a function

Tags: haskell

I've downloaded WinHugs 2 hours ago and still can't figure out how to declare simple things. I'm trying to follow the book "7 languages in 7 weeks", but stuff like `let x = 10` and `double x = x * 2` gives syntax errors.

Comment: Can you provide us with the exact error messages or a transcript of a small WinHugs session?

Comment: Check the only answer comments

Comment: @monadic: It seems the course requires it. Which, in turn, invites the more sociological question: "Why are courses in Haskell still being taught using WinHugs?" (or Gofer, heaven forbid!). Maybe a 'Guerrilla Guide to using the Glorious Haskell Compiler' is in order? Hugs used to be nice, and GHC was intimidating; but the tables have turned...

Comment: @yatima2975 requiring Windows in itself for a haskell course is just plain evil

Comment: @monadic: I'm a Windows guy myself, but for introductory courses, a recent-ish version of the Haskell Platform should take care of all incompatibility problems - unless they want to get into graphics in the first semester (and then WinHugs isn't much use, in the first case). Anyway, I blame academic inertia and I also have the feeling I'm preaching to the choir here :)

Comment: @yatima2975 I said that because iirc windows ghc doesn't yet support 64 bit, so all Int64 operations are still libgmp even if it is on a 64-bit platform. Thats a major show-stopper.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do that doesn't work. You can't declare bindings in a WinHugs session, you can only evaluate full expressions. So you could do things like `let x = 10 in x * x + x`, but you can't say `let x = 10` in an interactive session. In other words, you can't make the declaration 'stick'.

To get around this, either put your declarations in a `.hs` file and load it in WinHugs, or use GHCi instead (this is the better option, in my opinion - WinHugs is pretty dated). You can install GHCi by downloading [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm actually taking a university course in Haskell and must use WinHugs. I've loaded a `.hs` file, but still have problems. It looks like it skips 1st line for some reason. E.g.: test.hs: `x = 10
double y = y * 2
v = 10` in WinHugs: `Main> v
10` but `Main> x
ERROR - Undefined variable "x"
`

Comment: Feel free to open a separate question for that.

Comment: It's a bit hard to see where your linebreaks are, maybe you can edit your question with this new information? Anyway, check your indentation: are all the declarations lined up properly (at the first column, no tabs in the file etcetera)? Finally, tell your instructor to get with the program: she/he should update the course, since GHCi has been the Haskell interpreter of choice for a couple of years now :)

Comment: @Sara: The last thing to try is to add a first line which is not important to the rest of the program, maybe something like `module Main where` (this is implicitly added, anyway) or `foo = undefined`, or even `theAnswerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverything = 42` (if you have a TA who enjoys that kind of humour, but make sure to add a comment _why_ you're adding that!)

Comment: Turned out it was a problem with the text encoding, switched the text editor and started my journey into Haskell :D

Comment: I'm glad to hear you've fixed it! Little things like encodings and choosing a good editor can turn into major speedbumps, but you've overcome this one. It should be all fun from here on, I hope - and if not, just ask another question!

Answer (score 1):

in winhugs the following gives a syntax error

let double x = x * 2

but the following works:

let double x = x * 2 in double 10

however in ghc they have the interactive environment ghci where everything works

let double x = x * 2

works

double 10

works

this link explains how to work with ghci environment: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.2.2/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html

One minor issue is that on windows you need the presence of cygwin - otherwise ghci as compiled for windows will not work.

Comment: What does this add to the previous, over four year old, answer?

Comment: @dfeuer the four year old answer did not mention that in order for ghci to work you need to install cygwin (unlike winhugs - which is self contained). also my answer deals with the expression that was mentioned in the question. it tells you what worked and what didn't work for me.